# Is it possible to synchronise a .ics subscription URL with a Nextcloud calendar?

Tags: sync, calendar

I added some .ics (iCalendar/ical) subscription links to my Nextcloud calendar via the web interface. Now that I logged in to Nextcloud in GNOME's settings, these are not synchronised and do not appear in GNOME Calendar. I can add them manually, of course, but I would prefer to only have to log in with my Nextcloud account and have everything immediately wherever I go. Note that I want the iCalendar links to continue to be updated, not just import them. Is this possible, and if so how?

Answer (score 0):

You can set it up under GNOME Online Accounts.

Just add an Nextcloud Account using
Server: example.com[/nextcloud]
Username: ncuser
Password: s3cr3t!

It will ask you whether to use the account for synchronization of Calendar, Contacts, Documents and/or Files.

You can then go to the Manage your calendars > Manage calendars ... in the upper right corner to enable / disable individual calendars synchronized from Nextcloud.

In GNOME Calendar you can force synchronization with your Nextcloud Events by selecting Manage your calendars > Synchronize Calendars.

I personally prefer to add them the documented way to my Ligthning Calendar in Thunderbird as I am used to the workflow.

Comment: I did this, but unfortunately only the events I added manually are synchronised, not the ones imported from the .ics file/link.

Comment: While in Gnome Calendar there are three buttons in the top right corner.
Search for Events, Manage your Calendars and Main menu.
The Manage your Calendars > Synchronize Calendars should synchronize them right away. Other than that I also had the impression that it takes some time to sync.